# How to get textbox value via button click Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 input's:

```
<td><input id='someName_1' type='textbox' value='1' /><td>
<td><input id='someID_1' class="button1" type='button' value='Submit' /></td>
```

I have below ajax code:

```
$("body").on('click', '.button1', function () {
    var params = { id: this.id, value: (?) };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action(SomeUrl- pointless)',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf­8',
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        success: function (data, status) {
            doingsomething
        },
        error: function (er, info) {

        },
        complete: function (xhr, status) {

        },
    });
});
```

Question is: how i can get value in variable 'params', field 'value' from textbox with someID_1, if all my id's are created dynamically via response from server? Input's are too created dinamically.

There is code which generated my input's:

```
var s = [];
$.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
                var t = "<td><input id='someName_" + item.id + "' type='textbox' value='1' /></td>" +
                "<td><input id='someID_" + item.id + "' class='button1' type='button' value='Submit' /></td></tr>";
                s.push(t);                   
            });
$('body').html(s.join(""));
```

Comment: How dynamic are the inputs, can you add extra classes? Can you guarantee there will only be 2 inputs?

Comment: I quarantee it, cuz i get in response list of items, and for each of them created 2 input's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your DOM is a bit problematic you will have to traverse to the previous `td` element and take the input from there.

Here is an example:

```
$("body").on('click', '.button1', function () {
    input = $(this).parent('td').prev('td').children('input[type=textbox]')
    var params = { id: $(this).attr('id'), value: input.val() };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action(SomeUrl- pointless)',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf­8',
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        success: function (data, status) {
            doingsomething
        },
        error: function (er, info) {

        },
        complete: function (xhr, status) {

        },
    });
});
```

Comment: I cant use it, cuz there are maybe a lot of input's, or only one, so i dont know it, depending response from server

Comment: This code works for all of the inputs. You want just one of them?

Comment: Yes, i need that textbox, what is pair with button i clicked

Comment: Input's are located in <td>'s tags. Do u think subling() is works?

Comment: Anyway, thanks u man, i just recostruct my table for subling and it's works.

Comment: Well, I just updated my answer to work with your structure :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I see an issue here, but maybe I misunderstood the question?

Basically, you can pick up any DOM element that has any ID, by using jquery with:

```
$("#MY_RANDOM_ID")
```

so you can access its value (user input or automatically generated input) with:

```
$("#MY_RANDOM_ID").val()
```

Comment: Yeah, i knew it, problem is i dont know actually what id, i just can get it, by placing it into input's via <input name= "some value">